# Automatically freeing memory on exit in a shared library

Tags: c, unix

My goal is to wrap `malloc()` with my own implementation and then inject that implementation into executables using `LD_PRELOAD` trick for educational purposes.

I've made two files, `test.c` for testing the injection and `wrapper.c` which wraps `malloc()` and is compiled as a shared library.

My question is this:

Is it possible for `wrapper` to detect that it's caller, `test` is done (at the end of `main()`) to free it's memory (`dynamic_array`)?

I can't add something like `deinit()` to `wrapper` because I don't necessarily have access to caller's code like I do in the case of `test`.

I know it might be best to do it using RAII in C++, but what can be done in C?

```c
// test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    (void)malloc(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Built with:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

```c
// wrapper.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void* (*real_malloc)(size_t size) = NULL;

// Untested pseudocode, but you get the idea
void *dynamic_array = NULL;
unsigned dynamic_array_idx = 0;
size_t dynamic_array_size = 100;

void add_ptr(void* ptr)
{
    if (!dynamic_array) {
        dynamic_array = real_malloc(dynamic_array_size );   
    }
    
    if (dynamic_array_idx >= dynamic_array_size) {
        dynamic_array_size *= 2;
        dynamic_array = realloc(dynamic_array, dynamic_array_size);
    }

    dynamic_array[dynamic_array_idx++] = ptr;
}

void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (real_malloc == NULL) {
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    }
    
    void* ptr = real_malloc(size);
    add_ptr(ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

Built with:

```
gcc -c -fPIC -o wrapper.o wrapper.c
gcc -shared -o wrapper.so wrapper.o
```

Ran with:

```
LD_PRELOAD=wrapper.so ./test
```

Comment: there is no real need to do it at the end of the application. You can also register a destruction function using `atexit()`;

Comment: With gcc you can access the same mechanism used to call C++ destructors using `__attribute__((destructor))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `real_malloc` is initialized, you can use `atexit` to designate a function to be called when the program exits.  You can use this to clean up your memory.

Also, `dynamic_array` should have type `void **` to store an array of `void *`.

```
void cleanup(void)
{
    free(dynamic_array);
}

void* malloc(size_t size)
{
    if (real_malloc == NULL) {
        real_malloc = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
        atexit(cleanup);   // register cleanup handler
    }
    
    void* ptr = real_malloc(size);
    add_ptr(ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: I guess this will break if the main program `dlclose`s the library before exiting?

Comment: @NateEldredge The library is never `dlopen`'ed, just injected via `LD_PRELOAD`, so it shouldn't be an issue.